# Upgrading onboard GPU while replacing mainboard possible?

Tags: motherboard, gpu, zenbook

I have a Zenbook ux32vd needing a new mainboard. While at it I figured why not get one with a better onboard GPU.

1. Is this possible on principle?
2. How would you go about finding something like this? How are the chances of finding a mainboard with irregular onboard GPU or an empty slot?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: nope the GPU is part of the CPU. The dedicated GPU chip is most of the time added directly to the motherboard

Comment: Only the Intel GPU is part of the CPU, the Nvidia GT 620m has it's own slot (still glued on though, which is why I need a mainboard already produced with a better one)

Comment: "Is this possible on principle?" No; It's not;

Comment: dedicated card is the nvidia one, I haven't told that this one is part of the CPU *facepalm *. It is likely that the nvdia one has no slot/socket. There is a Mobile PCI Express Module , bit this was never really used by notebook vendors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The onboard GPU of these kind of computers is NOT a part of the motherboard.
The motherboard only provides the wiring (and some minimal electronics) that connects the video-output of the CPU to the LCD panel and/or an external connector (like a HDMI or DisplayPort).
The GPU is integrated in the CPU itself. So replacing the motherboard won' get you a better GPU.
Another CPU might do the trick, if it fits and is compatible with your laptop.

Compatiblity is the main issue anyway. In a desktop computer you can more or less swap parts as you like, but in a laptop it is VERY unusual to be able to replace motherboard or CPU with a model different from the one you already had. Laptop motherboards are often custom-designed for a particular model of laptop and the Bios is only able to handle a very specific list of CPU models.

P.S.
There exists motherboards with a separate GPU on the motherboard, but these are mainly found in high-end laptops and all-in-one computers (like an iMac).

I see from your comment you have the variant with the Nvidia GT-620m. This is indeed one of these high-end versions.
In that case: It might just be possible if Asus also makes a model that is completely the same except for the GPU. It could be possible that that board would find in the laptop casing and has all the wiring to external connectors and LCD panel the same.
I would NOT just bet on it and blindly order the motherboard. I have seen far too many laptops that looked identical on the outside, but had quite different internals. Even on the same model a revision A and a revision B of the hardware could have significant differences.